# How to force a method to be overridden in java?

Tags: java

I have to create a lot of very similar classes which have just one method different between them. So I figured creating abstract class would be a good way to achieve this. But the method I want to override (say, method foo()) has no default behavior. I don't want to keep any default implementation, forcing all extending classes to implement this method. How do I do this?

Comment: Sounds like an implementation of the Template Method Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: This is an excellent question for cases where you want ALL subclasses to call their parent.  The answers so far seem to have not considered that case.  Example: ensure a method needs to overridden in every class and call the parent: `@override protected void importantMethod(){ super.importantMethod(); ... }`

Comment: I was looking for an answer to the comment that @will posted and found
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046748/force-non-abstract-method-to-be-overridden

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need an **abstract** method on your base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract void foo();
}
```

This way, you don't specify a default behavior **and** you force non-abstract classes inheriting from `BaseClass` to specify an implementation for `foo`.

Comment: your base class `BaseClass` **must** be abstract.

Comment: ah right! I was under the misconception that abstract classes canot have non-abstract methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Just define foo() as an abstract method in the base class:

```
public abstract class Bar {
   abstract void foo();
}
```

See [The Java™ Tutorials (Interfaces and Inheritance)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

Just make the method abstract.

This will force all subclasses to implement it, even if it is implemented in a super class of the abstract class.

```
public abstract void foo();
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the superclass scenario

Answer (score 5):

If you have an abstract class, then make your method (let's say `foo` abstract as well)

```
public abstract void foo();
```

Then all subclasses will have to override `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

Make this method `abstract`.