# Force non-abstract method to be overridden

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have a method `String foo()` in an abstract class which already does a few precomputations but can't deliver the final result the method is supposed to return. So what I want is that each non-abstract class inheriting from my abstract class has to implement `foo` in a way that first `super()` is called and then the result is computed. Is there a way to force this in java?

Comment: please share the method signature for foo

Comment: Have it call an abstract method which needs to either perform the final calculations or return value(s) that it needs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, by redesigning to use the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and including an abstract method:

```
public abstract class AbstractSuper {
    public final String foo() {
        // Maybe do something before calling bar...
        String initialResult = bar();
        // Do something common, e.g. validation
        return initialResult;
    }

    protected abstract String bar();
}
```

Basically if you want to force subclasses to override a method, it *does* have to be abstract - but that doesn't have to be the method that is called by other code...

Comment: Is there a convention on how to call the two methods? I would give them the same name (which is of course not possible) because basically they do the same thing.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Do they? The `abstract` method performs a different part of the whole calculation, so it should have an according name. The same name might cause some misunderstanding on how to implement the abstract method in a child class.

Comment: @Tom Yeah that's true. It performs a different part. But usually I call my methods by what they return and not by what they do. For example in my current case I just want to count the number of method calls, so my `foo` looks like `counter++; return bar();`. By the way: Is it possible to prohibit the call of the abstract method in the classes which implement it?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: I have a convention of using `Impl` as a suffix for "implementation" methods, but that's not necessarily widespread. And no, you can't prohibit calling the abstract methods from within the implementation classes, and I don't think you *should*. The implementation class is providing the code - why shouldn't it be able to call it?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this in Java. However you can declare one more method which is abstract and call it. Like this:

```
public final String foo() {
    String intermediate = ... // calculate intermediate result;
    return calculateFinalResult(intermediate);
}

protected abstract String calculateFinalResult(String intermediate);
```

This way you will be forced to override `calculateFinalResult`. No calling of `super` instance is necessary. Also subclasses will not be able to redefine your `foo()` as it's declared as `final`.

Comment: Just a note: it is a good idea to use a suitable sorting of the modifiers (e.g. `protected` and `abstract`). You can find a recommended sorting here: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.8.7-modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
public abstract class MyBean { 

    public final String foo(){
        String preFinalResult = [...];
        return doFinalResult(preFinalResult)
    }

    protected abstract String doFinalResult(String preFinal);
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to change the modifier of `doFinalResult` from `public` to `protected`, so other classes (except child classes and classes in the same package) can't access it directly.