# Can I force the explicit use of @Override?

Tags: java, swing, overriding

Is there a way to force the use of @Override annotation?

Just to clarify, I'm not asking "how do I force a subclass to implement a method" (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203965/how-to-force-a-method-to-be-overridden-in-java)):

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract void foo();
}
```

I'm asking about this scenario specifically:

```
public class AnnotatedSubclass extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("I have @Override.");
    }
}

public class NonAnnotatedSubclass extends BaseClass {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("I do not have @Override.");
    }
}
```

Note that both compile, even though `NonAnnotatedSubclass` doesn't have an explicit `@Override` annotation.  Is there a way to make the compiler throw an error/warning in the case of `NonAnnotatedSubclass`?

I ask, because sometimes when I extend classes I accidentally override parent methods because they have names similar to ones I would create (like `.paint()` in Swing).

Comment: Your IDE can tell you when this happens and auto fix all the method which could have `@Override` but don't.

Comment: "'m not referring to abstract methods" Oh but you should be, if it overrides a method in `BaseClass`.

Comment: [Google's errorprone](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MissingOverride) has a check for this to require them at compile time.

Comment: you should use certain static analysis tool and try to create your rules for overrided methods. Never tried to do that, though.

Comment: I think the simple rule to follow is always use @override each time you intend to override a method. Check this stack overflow question for using static analysis tools for enforcing "@override" & thereby prevent unintentional overrides: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794382/how-to-enforce-usage-of-the-override-annotation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java compiler does not explicitly force the use of @Override annotation. To do so would break backwards compatibility with pre-Java5 code.

However, static analysis tools can enforce exactly the kind of thing you want. I mostly use [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) to enforce use of @Override. It has an explicit [rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_annotation.html#MissingOverride) for use of `@Override` and it can be integrated into all the standard Java build tools - Maven, Gradle, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize @Override wasn't in all versions of Java (which explains why it's an optional annotation)

Comment: It looks like checkstyle can enforce usage of `@Override` only if overriding method has javadoc with `{@inheritDoc}` tag :(